# How do I deal with locale of URL in Spree i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'd like to fix url duplicating locale like this.
http://localhost:3000/ja/shop/ja/products/apache-baseball-jersey/'

I set spree with spree_i18n on my rails app the other day.
And set Gemfile like this.

```
# Spree
gem 'spree', '~> 3.7.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.4'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n'
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize'
gem 'spree_paypal_express', github: 'spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express'
```

Also, here's my routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/ do
   get '/' => 'frontpage#index'
   mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/shop
```

My default locale is English and supporting locale is Japanese.
The ideal url is like 'https://somedomain/(locale)/product'.

So how should I do?

Comment: Go to http://spree-commerce.slack.com/ to get answers quickly.

Comment: I see your opinion

Answer (score 0):

#### Locale duplicate

Seems to me like Spree's engine and `spree_i18n` already handle the locale-based routing.

Removing `scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ja/` should remove the duplicate.

#### Removing '/shop'

If you want 'https://somedomain/(locale)/product' to be your URL, then that means removing '/shop' from it. You can do so by mounting spree's engine directly on the root: `mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/`. Mind that by doing that, any route that you add yourself might conflict with those defined by the engine.

Comment: Thanks! That could be helpful. I have to apologize about what I wrote earlier.
I'd like to make url  'https://somedomain/(locale)/shop/product' .
In this case, should I have to leave it 'mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/shop.' ?